# Clone an object except for given properties for each key

Tags: javascript-objects, destructuring

Sorry for the title, I couldn't really sum it all up.

I can't think of an easy way of doing what i'm trying to achieve.
Basically i have a big object which serves as a map of this kind:

```
{
    'room_id_1': {users:{}, property1: x, property2: y, property3: [...]},
    'room_id_2': {users:{}, property1: x, property2: y, property3: [...]},
}
```

I need to send parts of this object via WebSockets, but it can get quite big and i don't need all of its data, just some properties for each room_id. Refering to the example above, say i don't need to send property2 and property3, which is a very big array.

So my question is, what is the best way i can create an object with the same data structure, just without said properties for each key (or clone just the other properties, which i know and are finite)?
That is:

```
{
    'room_id_1': {users:{}, property1: x},
    'room_id_2': {users:{}, property1: x},
}
```

There's just another implication, that might matter: property2 might also be undefined.
est
I think there might be an elegant ES6 solution using Destructuring assignements, but i can't come up with one myself: i'm new to the syntax and i just can't see how i could do it.

Comment: Can you just send the properties you want and construct the object on the other side?

Comment: Actually, that might work pretty well, thanks!
Would still be interesting to see a solution to the problem in the case i couldn't do that though.

Comment: Why would you send extra data across the wire if you didnt need to?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

```
var bigObject = {
        'room_id_1': {users:{}, property1: 3, property2: 5, property3: [1, 2, 3, 4]},
        'room_id_2': {users:{}, property1: 6, property2: 9, property3: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
};

Object.keys(bigObject)
    .reduce((prev, propKey) => {
        let newObj = {};
        ['users', 'property1'].forEach(eachKey => {
                newObj[eachKey] = bigObject[propKey][eachKey];
        });
        prev[propKey] = newObj;
        return prev;
    }, {});
```

[image]